# How do i reduce the empty space under the footer in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Have been trying to fix this issue for that i Have tried Several ways to fix this but they didn't solve.

```
overflow-x : hidden;

min-height : 100%;

margin : 0px;
```

[image]

Code:

body:

```
    background-color : White;
    margin : 0px;
    padding : 0px;
    box-sizing : border-box;
    overflow-x : hidden;
```

Code:

```
    position : relative;
    display : flex;
    background-color : #191414;
    bottom : 190px;
    height : 170px !important;
    width : 1178px;
    max-width : 100%;
    justify-content : left;
    align-items : left;
    border : 5px solid blue;
```

Comment: please provide [mcve] of your page with footer

Comment: Yes! I Have Uploaded the image

Comment: Don't forget to add the _"minimal reproducible example"_, because without it we can only guess.

Comment: Have you ever used your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)? You can use them here. Hover the mouse-cursor over the empty space after the footer, right-click and select "Inspect". You should now see the "inspector", or "elements", in your developer tools with the HTML tag selected that causes the extra space.

Comment: please include html

Comment: Also remember that the minimum height of a web-page is equal to the real height of the browser window. If you have very little page content, not filling a whole window, you can have empty space below the footer. The trick to deal with this is to give the `<body>` tag a darker background color, and set the background color of your content to a lighter color, such a white. That way you clearly indicate where the page ends.

Comment: BigThanks. It almost solved my problem but little gap is still there i couldn't fix that even i tried to decrease height in my webpage.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use a `display:table` for the whole document and `display:table-row` with `height:0` for the footer.

Comment: Didn't helps me

Comment: I have no idea how this would change anything **under** the footer. Here "under" probably means "after"?

Comment: Yes! After the footer